# Subset a data.table to get the most recent 3 or more rows within a duration by group

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a faster way to subset a data.table within groups keeping the most recent 3 or more dates that occurred within 2 years?

I have a set of data with a grouping column and a date column and I need keep the most recent 3 or more dates within 2 years.

I wrote a function that takes a data.table for an object and uses a for loop to calculate the date[i] - date before it subsets the rows and break the loop if there are at least 3 dates that occurred within a year. This function is then applied to the data which was sorted by grouping in ascending order and date in descending order. It works but takes quite a bit of time to run.

```
# Loading packages --------------------------------------------------------

library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# Generating test data ----------------------------------------------------

test.dt <- data.table(grouping = c(rep(1, times = 17),
                                   rep(2, times = 30),
                                   rep(3, times = 7),
                                   rep(4, times = 9),
                                   rep(5, times = 8)),
                      date = c(sample(seq(dmy('28/8/2007'), dmy('3/10/2017'),
                                          by = 'day'), 17),
                               sample(seq(dmy('7/5/2007'), dmy('19/4/2016'),
                                          by = 'day'), 30),
                               sample(seq(dmy('28/12/2011'), dmy('3/10/2013'),
                                          by = 'day'), 7),
                               sample(seq(dmy('21/12/2007'), dmy('11/11/2010'),
                                          by = 'day'), 9),
                               sample(seq(dmy('27/8/2007'), dmy('5/2/2012'),
                                          by = 'day'), 8)))

# Filtering function ------------------------------------------------------

filter.fun <- function(dt) {

  for (i in seq_len(length(dt$date) - 2)) {

    temp <- dt[date[i] - date <= dyears(2) &
                 date[i] - date >= dyears(0),
               less_than_2years := "Yes"]

    if(temp[less_than_2years == "Yes", .N] >= 3){
      filtered_temp <- temp[less_than_2years == "Yes"
                            ][, less_than_2years := NULL]

      return(filtered_temp)

      break()
    }
  } else {temp[, less_than_2years := NULL]}
}

# Sorting data.table ------------------------------------------------------

setorder(test.dt, group, -date)

# Applying function to data.table by grouping -----------------------------

test.dt <- mydata.dt[
  , {
    SD_copy <- copy(.SD)
    filter.fun(SD_copy)},
  by = group]
```

Applying the function to the full set of data (~139,000 rows) takes around ~76.268s to complete. Is there a more efficient/quicker way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### EDIT: Corrected interpretation of question

It seems I had misinterpreted OP's requirements.

Now, I understand that the OP wants to find

1. for each `group`
2. the most recent sequence of dates
3. which lie all within a period of two years and
4. which consist of three or more entries.

This can be solved by *grouping in a non-equi join* to cover requirements (1) and (3) and subsequent filtering for requirement (4) and subsetting for requirement (2). Finally, the indices are retrieved of the affected rows of `test.dt`.:

```
setorder(test.dt, group, -date)
idx <- test.dt[.(group = group, upper = date, lower = date - years(2)), 
               on = .(group, date <= upper, date >= lower), .N, by = .EACHI][
                 N >= 3, seq(.I[1L], length.out = N[1L]), by = group]$V1
test.dt[idx]
```

> ```
>     group       date idx     age_yr
>  1:     1 2017-03-08   1 0.00000000
>  2:     1 2016-10-27   2 0.36164384
>  3:     1 2016-09-19   3 0.46575342
>  4:     1 2015-05-27   4 1.78356164
>  5:     2 2016-04-17   1 0.00000000
>  6:     2 2016-03-24   2 0.06575342
>  7:     2 2015-09-16   3 0.58630137
>  8:     2 2015-02-09   4 1.18630137
>  9:     2 2014-09-19   5 1.57808219
> 10:     2 2014-08-24   6 1.64931507
> 11:     2 2014-06-01   7 1.87945205
> 12:     2 2014-05-09   8 1.94246575
> 13:     2 2014-04-21   9 1.99178082
> 14:     3 2013-07-02   1 0.00000000
> 15:     3 2013-04-13   2 0.21917808
> 16:     3 2013-03-18   3 0.29041096
> 17:     3 2012-10-31   4 0.66849315
> 18:     3 2012-10-30   5 0.67123288
> 19:     3 2012-10-03   6 0.74520548
> 20:     3 2012-06-01   7 1.08493151
> 21:     4 2010-08-06   1 0.00000000
> 22:     4 2009-11-17   2 0.71780822
> 23:     4 2009-06-19   3 1.13150685
> 24:     4 2009-04-15   4 1.30958904
> 25:     4 2009-02-20   5 1.45753425
> 26:     4 2008-11-18   6 1.71506849
> 27:     4 2008-10-24   7 1.78356164
> 28:     5 2011-07-13   1 0.00000000
> 29:     5 2011-01-19   2 0.47945205
> 30:     5 2010-07-18   3 0.98630137
> 31:     5 2009-10-10   4 1.75616438
>     group       date idx     age_yr
> ```

Please, note that I have used the same  `set.seed(1L)` as in [IceCreamToucan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53899022/3817004) when creating `test.dt` to compare both results.

#### Wrong interpretation of question

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to keep for each group *either* the most recent 3 dates (regardless how old) *or* all dates which occurred within the last 2 years counted from the most recent date (even if more than 3).

The approach below uses the `data.table` special symbol `.I` which holds the row number (or index)  in the original data.table `x` while grouping.

So, the indices of the three most recent dates for each group can be determined by

```
setorder(test.dt, group, -date)
test.dt[, .I[1:3], keyby = group]
```

> ```
>     group V1
>  1:     1  1
>  2:     1  2
>  3:     1  3
>  4:     2 18
>  5:     2 19
>  6:     2 20
>  7:     3 48
>  8:     3 49
>  9:     3 50
> 10:     4 55
> 11:     4 56
> 12:     4 57
> 13:     5 64
> 14:     5 65
> 15:     5 66
> 16:     6 72
> 17:     6 73
> 18:     6 74
> ```

The indices of the dates which occurred within the last two years counted from the most recent date can be determined by

```
test.dt[, .I[max(date) <= date %m+% years(2)], keyby = group]
```

Here, `lubridate`'s date arithmetic is used to avoid problems with leap years.

Both set of indices can be combined using a set `union()` operation which removes duplicate indices. This set of indices is then used to subset the original data.table:

```
setorder(test.dt, group, -date)
test.dt[test.dt[, union(.I[1:3], .I[max(date) <= date %m+% years(2)]), keyby = group]$V1]
```

> ```
>     group       date idx     age_yr
>  1:     1 2017-04-18   1 0.00000000
>  2:     1 2017-02-22   2 0.15068493
>  3:     1 2016-09-15   3 0.58904110
>  4:     1 2016-08-26   4 0.64383562
>  5:     1 2016-07-26   5 0.72876712
>  6:     1 2015-08-14   6 1.67945205
>  7:     2 2016-03-26   1 0.00000000
>  8:     2 2015-12-08   2 0.29863014
>  9:     2 2015-11-21   3 0.34520548
> 10:     2 2015-05-23   4 0.84383562
> 11:     2 2015-04-22   5 0.92876712
> 12:     2 2014-06-08   6 1.80000000
> 13:     3 2013-07-02   1 0.00000000
> 14:     3 2013-05-23   2 0.10958904
> 15:     3 2012-10-24   3 0.68767123
> 16:     3 2012-10-06   4 0.73698630
> 17:     3 2012-06-16   5 1.04383562
> 18:     3 2012-03-15   6 1.29863014
> 19:     3 2012-01-26   7 1.43287671
> 20:     4 2010-07-20   1 0.00000000
> 21:     4 2010-02-21   2 0.40821918
> 22:     4 2009-11-19   3 0.66575342
> 23:     4 2009-08-04   4 0.95890411
> 24:     4 2009-01-26   5 1.47945205
> 25:     4 2009-01-17   6 1.50410959
> 26:     4 2008-07-26   7 1.98356164
> 27:     5 2011-04-10   1 0.00000000
> 28:     5 2011-04-04   2 0.01643836
> 29:     5 2011-04-01   3 0.02465753
> 30:     5 2011-03-05   4 0.09863014
> 31:     5 2010-12-28   5 0.28219178
> 32:     5 2009-08-23   6 1.63013699
> 33:     5 2009-08-07   7 1.67397260
> 34:     6 2021-02-21   1 0.00000000
> 35:     6 2018-12-03   2 2.22191781
> 36:     6 2014-09-11   3 6.45205479
>     group       date idx     age_yr
> ```

Please, note that `idx` and `age_yr` have been added to verify the result.

#### Data

I have added a 6th group of dates which represents the use case where 3 dates are picked regardless of age.

```
set.seed(123L)   # required for reproducible data
test.dt <- data.table(
  group = c(
    rep(1, times = 17),
    rep(2, times = 30),
    rep(3, times = 7),
    rep(4, times = 9),
    rep(5, times = 8),
    rep(6, times = 5)
  ),
  date = c(
    sample(seq(dmy('28/8/2007'), dmy('3/10/2017'), by = 'day'), 17),
    sample(seq(dmy('7/5/2007'), dmy('19/4/2016'), by = 'day'), 30),
    sample(seq(dmy('28/12/2011'), dmy('3/10/2013'), by = 'day'), 7),
    sample(seq(dmy('21/12/2007'), dmy('11/11/2010'),by = 'day'), 9),
    sample(seq(dmy('27/8/2007'), dmy('5/2/2012'), by = 'day'), 8),
    sample(seq(dmy('27/8/2001'), dmy('5/2/2029'), by = 'day'), 5)
  )
)
# add data to verify  result
test.dt[order(-date), idx := rowid(group)]
test.dt[, age_yr := as.integer(max(date) - date)/365, by = group]
test.dt
```

Comment: thank you for helping out Uwe but the interpretation of the question @IceCreamToucan was the right one. It took me a while to understand it when the question was posed to me too as there are so many layers of criteria to subset the data.

Comment: Thank you Uwe, it runs 100x faster than the function i wrote

Answer (score 2):

This will give the most recent group of >= 3 dates which are within 2 years of each other, for each value of `grouping`. The vector `close` is `TRUE` if the next two dates are within 2 years of the current date, else `FALSE` (i.e. `TRUE` if the group of three dates is "close"). Then `which.max(close)` is the index of the start of the first "close" group. So `date[which.max(close)] - date <= dyears(2)]` gives a logical vector which is `TRUE` for all dates within 2 years of the above-mentioned start-date, and putting it inside `.I[]` gives the corresponding row number.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo) # for the rollapply function
setorder(test.dt, grouping, -date)

new.fun <- function(x){
  close <- rollapply(x, 3, align = 'left', partial = T,
                     FUN = function(x) sum(x[1] - x <= dyears(2)) == 3)
  if(!any(close)) rep(FALSE, length(x))
  else x[which.max(close)] - x <= dyears(2)
}

inds <- test.dt[, .I[new.fun(date)], grouping]$V1

test.dt[inds]

#     grouping       date
#  1:        1 2017-03-08
#  2:        1 2016-10-27
#  3:        1 2016-09-19
#  4:        1 2015-05-27
#  5:        2 2016-04-17
#  6:        2 2016-03-24
#  7:        2 2015-09-16
#  8:        2 2015-02-09
#  9:        2 2014-09-19
# 10:        2 2014-08-24
# 11:        2 2014-06-01
# 12:        2 2014-05-09
# 13:        2 2014-04-21
# 14:        3 2013-07-02
# 15:        3 2013-04-13
# 16:        3 2013-03-18
# 17:        3 2012-10-31
# 18:        3 2012-10-30
# 19:        3 2012-10-03
# 20:        3 2012-06-01
# 21:        4 2010-08-06
# 22:        4 2009-11-17
# 23:        4 2009-06-19
# 24:        4 2009-04-15
# 25:        4 2009-02-20
# 26:        4 2008-11-18
# 27:        4 2008-10-24
# 28:        5 2011-07-13
# 29:        5 2011-01-19
# 30:        5 2010-07-18
# 31:        5 2009-10-10
#     grouping       date
```

Data Used:

```
set.seed(1)
test.dt <- data.table(grouping = c(rep(1, times = 17),
                                   rep(2, times = 30),
                                   rep(3, times = 7),
                                   rep(4, times = 9),
                                   rep(5, times = 8)),
                      date = c(sample(seq(dmy('28/8/2007'), dmy('3/10/2017'),
                                          by = 'day'), 17),
                               sample(seq(dmy('7/5/2007'), dmy('19/4/2016'),
                                          by = 'day'), 30),
                               sample(seq(dmy('28/12/2011'), dmy('3/10/2013'),
                                          by = 'day'), 7),
                               sample(seq(dmy('21/12/2007'), dmy('11/11/2010'),
                                          by = 'day'), 9),
                               sample(seq(dmy('27/8/2007'), dmy('5/2/2012'),
                                          by = 'day'), 8)))
```

Edit: Seems like Uwe's reading of the question is more plausible, just different from how I originally interpreted it. An example of when our results differ is if you run the above code block with `set.seed(81)`

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the explanation! Looks like I need to improve my familiarity with base R functions as I didn't know rollapply exists! I'll try it out when I have time on the full dataset before marking it as solved.

Comment: rollapply is from the zoo package

Comment: I just noticed my `close` computation was giving a warning, so I fixed that. Doesn't change the results, but should be without warning now.

Comment: your interpretation of the question was right but it seems to keep rows that aren't within 2 years of the maximum date too and it was also the same for the function i wrote. I added `else {temp[, less_than_2years := NULL]}` to circumvent the problem but how do I modify your answer to fix the problem?